# Make a html button open a website on the server side

Tags: html, apache, button

I'm pretty good with computers but I am no coder nor have I ever wrote more then a html text file on a website to show it being up to a customer. So I don't have any website coding experience.

But I am trying to make a simple website on my laptop (linux) with html or php if necessary (but prefer simple html)  that plays music to my sound boxes when I click a button.
Just a button opening a youtube playlist on the server. Usually you just make a button refer to another website but I need it to open on my laptop (server side) instead of opening the tab on the device that is visiting the website.

I can't really find anything on google or im not searching with the right keywords. So I thought I'd try here. Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: "play music or sound on server" is a whole different thing than "open a browser to play a youtube playlist". Popping up a browser _on the webserver_ sounds like a horrible idea. But follow @mplungjan's advice, this is way too broad.

Comment: > Popping up a browser on the webserver sounds like a horrible idea



Its my personal laptop on a private network behind a firewall that prohits anyone from outside from accessing it. its just a laptop it can't be that bad.